# Buffer video from url

Tags: android, webserver, ip

In my application I want to stream a video from a local IP(live streaming video) to my application and have to upload in another server. How can I do this?. I am working on this for the last two weeks. Anyone please help.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where has that failed?  We're not going to write everything for you

Comment: I can view that video using http method.I want to upload that video to another server.How is it possible? I have tried BufferedInputStream to stream the data, but its not working. I can't read anything